# Field with list of value, use in reports

Tags: qgis, forms

(QGIS 3.22.4) In the attribute table of a shapefile, I have a field with a list of values in the form. I am preparing a report, and I want to print the description of the value, not the value. When I select the field, only the value appears.
How to display the description?

As requested, this is a screenshot of the form:

[image]

When I refer to field Dir1a in the print, I got the value (0 to 9), but I want to print is the '12h-0°', '1h30-45°',...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the expression `represent_value("Dir1a")`, [see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#represent-value).